# How to remove duplicates and force elements in a numpy array to be unique using a given range?

Tags: python, numpy, permutation

In case of differential evolution, during mutation, the formula that is used most often is

```
arr[a] = (arr[b] + M * (arr[c] - arr[d])) % arr.shape[1]
```

Where
`arr` is a 2d array consisting of non-negative integers such that all elements in each row are unique,
`a` represents each row of `arr`,
`M` is the mutation constant ranging between 0 and 2 and
`b`, `c` and `d` are 3 unique random numbers.

However, on using this formula, I see that `arr[a]` has duplicate values based on the values of `arr[b]`, `arr[c]` and `arr[d]`. I wish to have only unique numbers in `arr[a]`. How is it possible using Numpy?

e.g.

```
arr[a] = [2, 8, 4, 9, 1, 6, 7, 3, 0, 5]
arr[b] = [3, 5, 1, 2, 9, 8, 0, 6, 7, 4]
arr[c] = [2, 3, 8, 4, 5, 1, 0, 6, 9, 7]
arr[d] = [6, 1, 9, 2, 7, 5, 8, 0, 3, 4]
```

On applying the formula, `arr[a]` becomes `[9, 7, 0, 4, 7, 4, 2, 2, 3, 7]`. But I want it to have only unique numbers between `0` and `arr.shape[1]`. I am open to modifying the mutation function if needed if M, arr[b], arr[c] and arr[d] are all used meaningfully.

Comment: Do you want a way to choose `b`, `c` and `d` in such a way that the final output only has unique values?

Comment: No, they can be anything provided no two elements are equal between a, b, c and d

Comment: np.unique  + np.vectorize ?

Comment: what is your initial definition of `arr`? Is it always a nx10 matrix? You want to have unique numbers between [0,10] based on which logic? Becuase the formula might return duplicates... b,c,d are randmly chosen in the interval 0, n-1?

Comment: Seems like your population is made of permutations. I'm not sure a differential makes so much sense if that is the case. This is a rather different approach, but if you think of it in terms of permutations, you could replace `(arr[c] - arr[d])` with "the permutation that takes you from `arr[d]` to `arr[c]`", and the `+` as the composition of permutation `arr[b]` with that "differential permutation". Not sure how you could bring in the `M` though (compose the permutation more than once?).

Comment: @alexandra: arr is always a nx10 array. I wish to have unique numbers between 0 and 10 by modifying the mutation formula.

Comment: @Wen-Ben: I don't understand. Could you please explain?

Comment: @jdehesa: Can you give one example to make things clear? I did not understand this part: "the permutation that takes you from arr[d] to arr[c]", and the + as the composition of permutation arr[b] with that "differential permutation"

Comment: @alexandra: Sorry, forgot to say that b, c and d are chosen between 0 and n-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather different approach to the problem, but since you seem to be working with permutations, I am not sure numerical differences are that meaningful. You can however see the problem in terms of permutations, that is, reordering of vectors. Instead of the difference between two vectors, you may consider the permutation that takes you from one vector to the other, and instead of the addition of two vectors, you may consider applying a permutation to a vector. If you want to have an `M` parameter, maybe that could be the number of times you apply the permutation? (assuming that is a non-negative integer)

Here is the basic idea of how you could implement this:

```
import numpy as np

# Finds the permutation that takes you from vector a to vector b.
# Returns a vector p such that a[p] = b.
def permutation_diff(a, b):
    p = np.zeros_like(a)
    p[a] = np.arange(len(p), dtype=p.dtype)
    return p[b]

# Applies permutation p to vector a, m times.
def permutation_apply(a, p, m=1):
    out = a.copy()
    for _ in range(m):
        out = out[p]
    return out

# Combination function
def combine(b, c, d, m):
    return permutation_apply(b, permutation_diff(d, c), m)

# Test
b = np.array([3, 5, 1, 2, 9, 8, 0, 6, 7, 4])
c = np.array([2, 3, 8, 4, 5, 1, 0, 6, 9, 7])
d = np.array([6, 1, 9, 2, 7, 5, 8, 0, 3, 4])
m = 1
a = combine(b, c, d, m)
print(a)
# [2 7 0 4 8 5 6 3 1 9]
```

Since you are working with many vectors arranged in a matrix, you may prefer vectorized versions of the above functions. You can have that with something like this (here I assume M is a fixed parameter for the whole algorithm, not per individual):

```
import numpy as np

# Finds the permutations that takes you from vectors in a to vectors in b.
def permutation_diff_vec(a, b):
    p = np.zeros_like(a)
    i = np.arange(len(p))[:, np.newaxis]
    p[i, a] = np.arange(p.shape[-1], dtype=p.dtype)
    return p[i, b]

# Applies permutations in p to vectors a, m times.
def permutation_apply_vec(a, p, m=1):
    out = a.copy()
    i = np.arange(len(out))[:, np.newaxis]
    for _ in range(m):
        out = out[i, p]
    return out

# Combination function
def combine_vec(b, c, d, m):
    return permutation_apply_vec(b, permutation_diff_vec(d, c), m)

# Test
np.random.seed(100)
arr = np.array([[2, 8, 4, 9, 1, 6, 7, 3, 0, 5],
                [3, 5, 1, 2, 9, 8, 0, 6, 7, 4],
                [2, 3, 8, 4, 5, 1, 0, 6, 9, 7],
                [6, 1, 9, 2, 7, 5, 8, 0, 3, 4]])
n = len(arr)
b = arr[np.random.choice(n, size=n)]
c = arr[np.random.choice(n, size=n)]
d = arr[np.random.choice(n, size=n)]
m = 1
arr[:] = combine_vec(b, c, d, m)
print(arr)
# [[3 6 0 2 5 1 4 7 8 9]
#  [6 1 9 2 7 5 8 0 3 4]
#  [6 9 2 3 5 0 4 1 8 7]
#  [2 6 5 4 1 9 8 0 7 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this:

```py
list(set(arr[a]))
```

Comment: But then I may no longer have arr.shape[1] number of elements in arr[a]. I cannot change the shape of the data.

Comment: But if you want just unique numbers, the shape will be different. How do you want to fill the rest of array? With zeros or ones,  for exemple?

Comment: I wish to have all integers between 0 and arr.shape[1]. So, I want to fill up the duplicates using the elements that are absent but should have been present.

Answer (score 0):

here is a example what could do:

```py
array = np.array([9, 7, 0, 4, 7, 4, 2, 2, 3, 7])
shape = array.shape[0]
array = list(set(array))
for i in range(shape):
    if i not in array:
        array.append(i)
array = np.array(array)
```

If you want to fill in the index of the numbers are duplicate, the logical is a little diffent. But the idea is that. I hope I helped you.

Comment: Thanks, I am ok with this idea. But it will be better to somehow have a vectorized numpy code and get rid of the for loop.